# Automatically run code on Pycharm environment start

Tags: python, automation, pycharm, python-import

I have just started using PyCharm because I want to get more into Python (have more experience with other languages), and have run into a conundrum that there has to be a solution for. Some custom function I created relies on a module being imported in a particularly verbose way, so I don't want to have to copy-paste the same two lines every time I want to code, as opposed to simply typing `import numpy as np`.

So is there a way to *automatically run some code on my environment's start*? Particularly to import some modules? I looked around PyCharm's settings, and have found nothing.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to accomplish: are you looking to _install_ modules automatically, or just add the `import` lines to the beginning of a file automatically, so you don't have to enter them by hand when writing code?

Comment: Just add the import lines at the beginning of my environment's startup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do `File | Settings | Tools | Startup Tasks`  (or `Ctrl-Alt-S`).

Then: `Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console`

This gives you a dialogue with an edit box *Starting script*. Put your import code there. That will run every time you open a new console.

Comment: Actually, I think it was working for a bit, but now it is not. I double-verified I put the script in the right place but it does not show up/work in my scratch files. https://imgur.com/a/Ul8Q2 
Could you help me out some more?

Comment: It will only work in console sessions. You have to put it in explicitly at the top of a saved program. Otherwise the program would fail when run outside of PyCharm.

Comment: If you want boilerplate import code in *every* file, consider using a template: `File | Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates`. Either edit the Python Script template to include the code you want, or create a new one.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XPrMr I have done as you said, and even restarted PyCharm a couple times for good measure, but it still is not recognizing my function. Any idea on why?

Comment: If you add code to a template, then you have to *create a new file* using that template, if you want to see new code in the resulting file. Changing the template doesn't retrofit new code into files you have already created. If you want a set of `import`s to run every time you start the interpreter (not just a Python console but at every execution) maybe you should look at writing `sitecustomize.py` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html9). I hesitate to recommend this because it can have baffling side-effects if you're not careful.